# Search keywords with enter key - BUG

Tags: javascript, .net

So, i'm developing a search feature in my website, and i want to redirect the user to a page with the keywords he is trying to search.

The following code works, but there is a bug: when i click enter in my homepage it works. The user is successfully redirected to my search page with the results. But when i'm in that page (or any other page) the enter key does not work! Only the button works all the time! It's a strange error and i dont know what to do...

This code is in my masterpage (.net 4.0) and it is the parent of all my webforms (including home). Can anyone help me?

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="TBPesquisa" runat="server" placeholder="Pesquise produtos aqui" onkeypress="return runScript(event)"></asp:TextBox>

<button id="BTPesquisa" class="button-search" type="button" onClick="javascript:window.location.assign('/Pesquisa?val='+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('TBPesquisa').value));">Pesquisar</button>
                                
<script>
  function runScript(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#BTPesquisa").click();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: do you have by any chance, other scripts that are called runScript?

Comment: No... This script is only used here...

Comment: And there is no other script with the same name

Comment: Did you check in the debugger, if you have an error on the other pages? For example, cannot get value of undefined (in case your `TBPesquisa` is not found?)

Comment: When i do this:

<script>
     function runScript(e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 13) {
               var test = $("#BTPesquisa");
               alert(test);
          }
     }
</script>

i get [Object Object] in my home page and in ther pages but... in chrome console the following error apears "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) :21741/undefined?1496853103683"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, the reason is that the `TBPesquia` field wasn't found, as this is an asp.net textbox control, and the ID might not be what you expect it to be.

Now you could either go for setting the `ClientID` property, like:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TBPesquisa" ClientID="TBPesquisa" runat="server" placeholder="Pesquise produtos aqui" onkeypress="return runScript(event)"></asp:TextBox>
```

or you could rewrite your handler slightly, by doing the following

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TBPesquisa" runat="server" placeholder="Pesquise produtos aqui" onkeypress="runScript(event)"></asp:TextBox>
```

and change the runscript to:

```
 function runScript(e) {
   var source = e.target;
   if (e.keyCode === 13) {
     searchFor( source.value );
     e.preventDefault();
   }  
 }

 function searchFor( textValue ) {
   window.location.assign('/Pesquisa?val=' + encodeURIComponent(textValue));
 }
```

I would btw rather put the code for searching outside of the searchbutton itself, it only makes sense to have this outside of your html element

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! And i will do that! :)